# Select a random object in a list

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a program that selects a random object in a list and then refer to that object.

Here's my code:

```
for hour in c.routine:
    a = hour.hour
    if hour.task == "idle":
        if c.spouse:
            if c.spouse[0].routine[a].task == "idle":
                if hour.hour >= 6 and hour.hour <= 19:
                    x = random.choice(family_daytime_activities)
                    hour.task = x
                    y = hour.hour+1
                    c.routine[y].task = x
                    c.spouse[0].routine[a].task = x
                    c.spouse[0].routine[y].task = x
                    if c.kids:
                        for k in range(len(c.kids)):
                            if c.kids[k].routine[a].task == "idle":
                                c.kids[k].routine[a].task = x
                                c.kids[k].routine[y].task = x
                else:
                    x = random.choice(family_nighttime_activities)
                    hour.task = x
                    y = hour.hour+1
                    c.routine[y].task = x
                    c.spouse[0].routine[a].task = x
                    c.spouse[0].routine[y].task = x
        elif c.lover:
            pick = random.choice(c.lover)
            if c.lover[pick].routine[a].task == "idle":
                c = random.randint(0,2)
                if c == 1:
                    if hour.hour >= 6 and hour.hour <= 19:
                        x = random.choice(daytime_activities)
                        hour.task = x
                        y = hour.hour+1
                        c.routine[y].task = x
                        c.lover[pick].routine[a].task = x
                        c.lover[pick].routine[y].task = x
                else:
                    x = random.choice(nighttime_activities)
                    hour.task = x
                    y = hour.hour+1
                    c.routine[y].task = x
                    c.lover[pick].routine[a].task = x
                    c.lover[pick].routine[y].task = x
```

When I run this code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures\Python\Westhope\2.0\exe.py", line 9, in
<module>
    routine_creation()   File "C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures\Python\Westhope\2.0\world_init.py", line
721, in routine_creation
    if c.lover[pick].routine[a].task == "idle": TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Seems to be the way I try to refer to the pick but I am not sure why or how to fix it...

Comment: You should try reading the exception.

Comment: `pick = random.choice(c.lover)` will return a random object from `c.lover`. You would refer to that object with `pick`, not `c.lover[pick]`

Comment: Have you debugged the value and type of `a` and `pick` just before your error?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code to comb through.  Could you make a smaller example?

According to your stack trace, the problem is at

```
if c.lover[pick].routine[a].task == "idle"
```

Okay, i see it.  Change

```
pick = random.choice(c.lover)
if c.lover[pick].routine[a].task == "idle":
```

to:

```
pick = random.choice(c.lover)
if pick.routine[a].task == "idle":
```

you already have a random choice made (it is contained in `pick`), so you can just use that directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you also need the index, use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

```
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(len(foo))
print(foo[random_index])
```